# tf.data.Dataset apply() doesn't update dataset

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm loading a dataset of images with `image_dataset_from_directory` and it gives me a `PrefetchDataset` with my images and their associated label one-hot encoded.

In order to build a binary image classifier, I want to transform my `PrefetchDataset` labels to know if an image is a photo or somethings else.

Here's how I wrote it:

```py
batch_size = 32
img_height = 250
img_width = 250

train_ds = image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  color_mode="rgb",
  subset="training",
  seed=69,
  crop_to_aspect_ratio=False,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = train_ds.class_names
# ['Painting', 'Photo', 'Schematics', 'Sketch', 'Text'] in my case

# Convert label to 1 is a photo or else 0
i = 1 # class_names.index('Photo')

def is_photo(batch):
    for images, labels in batch:
        bool_labels = tf.constant([int(l == 1) for l in labels],
                                  dtype=np.int32)
        labels = bool_labels
    return batch

new_train_ds = train_ds.apply(is_photo)
```

My problem is that the `new_train_ds` doesn't defers from `train_ds` which leads me to thinks there must be an issue with the `apply` method.
I also checked `bool_labels` and it works just fine.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this issue.

Comment: Well where is `i` defined in `is_photo`??

Comment: @AloneTogether oh I see, I edited the post to have the actual code but my problem still remains

Comment: So you want to convert class names that have the word `Photo` to 1 and the rest to 0?

Comment: Exactly, each labels is either 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 where 1 means its a photo.
So I would to convert the labels to 1 if photo and 0 else.

Comment: @AloneTogether I edited my previous comment to explain my thought process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```
train_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.cast(y == 1, dtype=tf.int64)))
```